# What's a cross-browser way to build 2-fixed-width-columns separated by fluid padding?

Tags: html, css, layout

Looking to build **2-fixed-width-columns**, each `width: 320px;` and `height: 95%;`

What's a good way to have them **centered** on the page, separated by a 15% padding/margin?

*Here's the prospective layout:*

[image: 2-fixed-width-columns, 320px wide, 95% page-height, with 15% in between]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this OP, the only problem I ran into was that I couldn't set the `wrapper {width: 100%}` I think it needs to be a set width, that isn't 100%. Anyway here is the codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zydKk

Comment: This is really great. Thanks for this.. One thing though, the whole-page triggers a vertical-scroll-bar, when it should (and by your code seems) be 100% height.. Any suggestions there?

Comment: Will definitely accept.. Just looking for the last tip there on the no-scroll-bar for height..

Comment: If you want to get rid of the scroll-bar use html { overflow-y: hidden; }

Comment: With html, body & overflow-y: hidden; the columns either stick to the top, or to the bottom of the window, randomly.. any suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't it do that already on the code pen, if you resize the html space you will see the height changes.

Comment: yeh, it actually looks prefect on codepen, with overflow-y: hidden; might be a firefox thing.. am checking it out.. accepted regardless because the codepen is really perfect.. any suggestions for the firefox rendering would be much appreciated..

Comment: What version of firefox are you using, it should work I just tested it on mine. My version is 24.0

Comment: 24 and 25.0a2 (2013-09-05).. padding-top: .5%; on the html, body.. did the trick.. curious though.. thanks again!

Comment: note that overflow-y doesn't work in old versions of IE, so make sure the site is functional without it.